# Proper Subspace and Linear Transformation from a Vector Space to a Field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over field $F$. Let $W$ be a proper subspace. I am supposed to prove that there exists $T: V \to F$ such that $T(W) = \{0\}$ and $T(V) \neq \{0\}$.

This confuses me a bit because $T$ is from $V$ to $F$ instead of a different vector space. I want to say this is related to the kernel because of $T(W) = \{0\}$ but I am not sure how to approach this at all. Any tips as to how should I approach this? The question says that 'this means $T$ vanishes on $W$ but not all of $V$', but I am still confused as to what this means.

Comment: $F$ is a vector space over $F$, of dimension $1$, so $T$ is a linear transformation between vector spaces. As to your question, what do you know about "basis" of a vector space? The lemma that a basis of a subspace can be extended to a basis of the whole space, is the key point to proving this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_1,\dots,a_k$ be a basis for $W$ and extend that to a basis $a_1,\dots,a_k,a_{k+1},\dots,a_n$ for $V$. Define $T: V \to F$ via $T(\sum_j c_j a_j) = c_{k+1}+\dots c_n$. This is a linear map with $T(W) = \{0\}$ and $T(V) \not = \{0\}$.